# How to accelerate Beautifulsoup in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I tried to parse 50 000 url using Beautifulsoup in Python.
The parsing works in loop:

I figure out that time for parsing one page is 15 - 18 seconds. From page I grab around 20 elements.

Why does Beautifulsoup work so slow? How to accelerate Beautifulsoup in Python?

Comment: use lxml library or use beautiful's lxml parser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you understand your bottlenecks.

The very first and the main problem is not the HTML parsing - it is "The parsing works in loop".

Which means that **the code is synchronous/blocking** - you are not processing the next URL until you are done with the current one. This is absolutely *not scalable*.

To solve this, switch to an asynchronous approach - switch to, for example, [`Scrapy`](http://scrapy.readthedocs.io) web-scraping framework - this is currently the most natural move for scaling web-scraping projects.

Also see:

- [Speeding up beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539330/speeding-up-beautifulsoup/25540330#25540330)

Answer (score 1):

Parallelize your processing.

e.g.

```
import Queue
import threading 

# will execute parrallel
def taskProcess(q, url):
    q.put(beautifulSoupFunction(url))

urls = ["http://url1.com", "http://url2.com"]

q = Queue.Queue()

for u in urls:
    t = threading.Thread(target=taskProcess, args = (q,u))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

s = q.get()
print s
```

Comment: Need I just put this in thread? `q.put(beautifulSoupFunction(url))`? Or all code below as: `title = soup.select('.document-title > .id-app-title')[0].text`?

Comment: I mean how to put this code to `Q`: ` soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

        web_site = ""
        title = soup.select('.document-title > .id-app-title')[0].text`

Comment: Frankly, that is a different question, not that I don't like to answer that.

Comment: In Python 3 I get error: `NameError: name 'Thread' is not defined`

Comment: Can you execute following reply ? 

>>> import threading
>>> def p(s):
...   print s
...
>>> t = threading.Thread(target=p, args=(["Hello"]))
>>> t.run
<bound method Thread.run of <Thread(Thread-2, initial)>>
>>> t.run()
Hello
>>>