# Making XML parser faster

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am currently writing a script that parses through a xml webpage using beautifulsoup. An example of the xml file is [here](http://www.deadstock.ca/sitemap_products_1.xml). The script basically will output the first product URL (from each 'loc' tag) which matches a list of keywords that have been inputted. Currently, the script's control flow is the following:

- pass the URL into a soup object and beautify it
- run a for loop for each url tag, and put each loc text into a list (inventory_url)

  ```
  for item in soup.find_all('url'):
          inventory_url.append(item.find('loc').text)
  ```
- iterate through the list, and output the first element that matches all keywords, where 'keywords' is the inputted list of keywords

  ```
      for item in inventory_url:
          if all(kw in item for kw in keywords):
              return item
  ```

I am wondering if there is a way to make the parsing faster. I have looked at soupstrainer, but when I isolate to only find 'loc' tags, it also takes in 'image:loc' tags, which I do not need.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you use [lxml](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) to parse the xml ?

Comment: Not yet. Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Are you sure that parsing is the bottleneck? If you are getting the webpages from the internet, I suspect that takes more than factor 1000 longer than parsing the page.

Comment: use `re` ? could be faster and likely powerful enough.. (note, I'm not too familiar with webscraping or beautifulsoup so I'm not sure if you'd run into slowdowns converting to a text stream to run your regex on)

Answer (score 0):

If you can stream the file as simple text, I presume regex would be pretty fast...

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'<url>[\S\s]*?<loc>([\S\s]*?)</loc>[\S\s]*?</url>')

for match in re.finditer(pattern, file.read()):
     #do stuff
```

the `[\S\s]*?` is a lazy way to match literally anything until we hit what comes next. The `?` is crucial to not making this break.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a different parser? https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use

Also see tips in:
[Speeding up beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539330/speeding-up-beautifulsoup)