# Trying to access a password protected url using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, urllib

I've had problems accessing www.bizi.si or more specifically 
http://www.bizi.si/BALMAR-D-O-O/ for instance. If you look at it without registering you won't see any financial data. But if you use the free registration, I used username: Lukec, password: lukec12345, you can see some of the financial data. I've used this next code:

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import re
import csv

username = 'Lukec'
password = 'lukec12345'
url = 'http://www.bizi.si/BALMAR-D-O-O/'
values = {'username':username, 'password':password}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url,data,values)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req,data)
respData = resp.read()

paragraphs = re.findall('<tbody>(.*?)</tbody>',str(respData))
```

And my len(paragraphs) is zero. I would really be grateful if anyone of you would be able to tell me how to access the page correctly. I know that the length being zero isnt the best indicator, but also the len(respData) if I use values as stated in my code or if I take it out of my code is the same, so I know I have not accessed the page through username, password.
Thank you for you're help in advance and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

1. You are not using POST, but GET for the request.
2. There is no `<tbody>` element in the HTML produced; any such tags have been automatically added by your browser, do not rely on them being there.

To create a POST request, use:

```
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, method='POST')
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

Note that I removed the `values` argument (those are not headers, the third positional argument to `Request()` and you don't pass in a `data` argument when using a `Request` object.

The resulting HTML returned does not necessarily include the same data that is sent to a browser; you probably need to maintain a *session* here, return the cookies that the site sets.

It is far easier to do this with better tools such as the [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (the latter lets you parse HTML without having to resort to regular expressions), which can be combined with the [robobrowser project](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to help you fill and submit forms on websites.

Note however that the page forms and state are managed by ASP.NET JavaScript code and are not easily reverse-engineered even by robobrowser. When you log in with a browser (which has run the JavaScript code for you), the POST looks like this:

```
{'__EVENTTARGET': ['ctl00$ctl00$loginBoxPopup$loginBox1$ButtonLogin'],
 '__VSTATE': ['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'],
 'ctl00$ctl00$SearchAdvanced1$ActivitiesAndProductsSearch1$RadioButtonList1': ['TSMEDIA '
                                                                               'dejavnost'],
 'ctl00$ctl00$SearchAdvanced1$DropDownListYearSelection': ['2013'],
 'ctl00$ctl00$SearchAdvanced1$SteviloZaposlenihDo': ['do'],
 'ctl00$ctl00$SearchAdvanced1$SteviloZaposlenihOd': ['od'],
 'ctl00$ctl00$SearchAdvanced1$ddlLegalEvents': ['0'],
 'ctl00$ctl00$loginBoxPopup$loginBox1$Password': ['lukec12345'],
 'ctl00$ctl00$loginBoxPopup$loginBox1$UserName': ['Lukec'],
 'ctl00_ctl00_ScriptManager1_HiddenField': [';;AjaxControlToolkit, '
                                            'Version=3.5.40412.0, '
                                            'Culture=neutral, '
                                            'PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e:sl:1547e793-5b7e-48fe-8490-03a375b13a33:475a4ef5:effe2a26:3ac3e789:5546a2b:d2e10b12:37e2e5c9:5a682656:12bbc599:1d3ed089:497ef277:a43b07eb:751cdd15:dfad98a5:3cf12cf1'],
 'hiddenInputToUpdateATBuffer_CommonToolkitScripts': ['1']}
```

That's a lot more information than a simple username / password combination.

See [post request using python to asp.net page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746750/post-request-using-python-to-asp-net-page) for approaches on how to handle such pages instead.

Comment: I've changed my code as suggested, but I still believe that the additional data is locked. For instance if I search for everything between all <thead> tags i get [] which I assume is the case because I am not allowed to access the data between. Any suggestions here? 
Thank you for everything above.

Comment: @Swish41: You cannot just post what you see in the browser; see [post request using python to asp.net page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14746750) for approaches on how to use that form here.